# Deriving the type of the value of a typed FormGroup in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

With the new typed form controls in Angular, we can do this:

```
interface MyFormGroup {
    id: FormControl<number | null>;
    name: FormControl<string | null>;
    email: FormControl<string | null>;
}
```

Which defines a type for each `FormControl` in the following `FormGroup`:

```
myFormGroup = new FormGroup<MyFormGroup>({
    id: new FormControl(42),
    name: new FormControl('Arthur'),
    email: new FormControl('arthur@dent.com')
});
```

The type of the value of this `FormGroup` would be:

```
Partial<{
    id: number | null;
    name: string | null;
    email: string | null;
}>
```

If I want to use the value of the `FormGroup` in a function, is there a shortcut to getting the type of the value, or must this be defined separately, e.g.

```
interface MyFormGroupValue {
    id: number | null;
    name: string | null;
    email: string | null;
}

myFunction(myFormGroupValue: MyFormGroupValue){
    console.log(myFormGroupValue);
}
```

Put another way, is it possible to derive the type `MyFormGroupValue` from `MyFormGroup`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and the [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) keyword will do the trick.

```
type ExtractFormControl<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends FormControl<infer U> ? U : T[K]
}

type MyFormGroupValue = ExtractFormControl<MyFormGroup>
// type MyFormGroupValue = {
//     id: number | null;
//     name: string | null;
//     email: string | null;
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFEsFsAcHsCcAuACA3sgYgyBhWA7ReWAG2QF9kAzYyZAcgAEBDfAcwFcTn4B6K7AGd6oCIQCm8KswDG45AFkAnlniQA4sQ7Q0oZPuTgAJgC5M2PIWIkAPPg6QARpOQAfZPZIkAfAG49BvjMkOJmqrgERKQ2gkTg7G4eXD7%20IAbI4pDM4CRhFpHWMXEJ7p4poOSiIIhK0PIAogAeRLKI4ZZRtgAq3sgAvLppBgDaANKG%20MgA1uJKsFTIXQC6Zl1jSxnN4vhGguZqHYXxVC4Aqr0A-MinyKvrFVU1dYoq2Jqw2gBqzCQc8v3IJotGRtfJWaLKcLvbTeUC8XjIJ7ySFvLTQb6-eQDVBwhHpYxmexOFylZKpeHpDzBULIWLweJsRJlcl4gyZbK5WnFRmkrwsihAA)

Answer (score 3):

Following up on the excellent answer from @Tobias S. If you have a `FormGroup` or `FormArray` with nested controls, you might need something that uses recursion to traverse the full structure like:

```
export type ExtractFormControl<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]
  : T[K] extends FormControl<infer U>
  ? U
  : T[K] extends FormArray<FormControl<infer U>>
  ? Array<U>
  : T[K] extends FormArray<FormGroup<infer U>>
  ? Array<Partial<ExtractFormControl<U>>>
  : T[K] extends FormGroup<infer U>
  ? Partial<ExtractFormControl<U>>
  : T[K]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending on Matt Saunders' answer, this will help if you have optional properties in your form, e.g:

```
// Interface with optional form controls
interface MyFormGroup {
    id?: FormControl<number | null>;
    name?: FormControl<string | null>;
    email?: FormControl<string | null>;
}
```

Updated `ExtractFormControl` to handle optional properties:

```
export type ExtractFormControl<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]
  : T[K] extends FormControl<infer U>
  ? U
  : T[K] extends (FormControl<infer U> | undefined)
  ? (U | undefined)
  : T[K] extends FormArray<FormControl<infer U>>
  ? Array<U>
  : T[K] extends (FormArray<FormControl<infer U>> | undefined)
  ? (Array<U> | undefined)
  : T[K] extends FormArray<FormGroup<infer U>>
  ? Array<Partial<ExtractFormControl<U>>>
  : T[K] extends (FormArray<FormGroup<infer U>> | undefined)
  ? (Array<Partial<ExtractFormControl<U>>> | undefined)
  : T[K] extends FormGroup<infer U>
  ? Partial<ExtractFormControl<U>>
  : T[K] extends (FormGroup<infer U> | undefined)
  ? (Partial<ExtractFormControl<U>> | undefined)
  : T[K]
}
```